# How to get editable ranges in Word with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

In a Word Document some ranges have been marked "editable" for everyone with `rng.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone`.

How can I get those "editable" ranges?

Calling `ActiveDocument.SelectAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone` will work only if all(!) the ranges have more than 0 chars. Empty string ranges cause a message telling that some ranges overlap and recomend using the Button "next editable range".

How can I use "next editable range" in VBA?

**UPDATE**: requested examples

The following examples create a Document with a simple formular: `Name: [] - Address: []`. In the first example there are no spaces between the brackets. In the second there is one space between the brackets. Both examples select the ranges within the brackets as editable ranges. The first example has two zero length editable ranges, the second two editable ranges with length 1. The ranges can be selected with `SelectAllEditableRanges` in the second example but not in the first one.

```
Sub TestZeroLengthEditableRanges()
    Documents.Add Template:="Normal", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0
    Selection.TypeText "Name: [] - Address: []"
    ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=7, End:=7).Select
    Selection.Editors.Add Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone
    ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=21, End:=21).Select
    Selection.Editors.Add Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone
    'The following opens a message telling the some ranges overlap
    ActiveDocument.SelectAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone
End Sub

Sub TestEditableRanges()
    Documents.Add Template:="Normal", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0
    Selection.TypeText "Name: [ ] - Address: [ ]"
    ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=7, End:=8).Select
    Selection.Editors.Add Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone
    ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=22, End:=23).Select
    Selection.Editors.Add Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone
    ActiveDocument.SelectAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone
End Sub
```

Comment: @CindyMeister: an "editable range" is a normal range marked as editable via the `Editors` collection. Ranges can also be zero lengthed. Actually the `Selection` is a zero length range when typing in word.

Comment: Thank you for the additional detail. It looks like McStack has provided the information you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Selection.GoToEditableRange wdEditorCurrent
```

or

```
Dim objEditor As Editor 
Dim objRange As Range 
Set objEditor = Selection.Editors(1) 
Set objRange = objEditor.NextRange
```